# Compute the union of intervals Elements of Programming Interviews 13.8 Python

Tags: python, algorithm, intervals, disjoint-sets

My program needs to output a list of interval objects expressed as a set of disjoint intervals. Assume True implies close ended ie:inclusive and False implied the endpoint is open ended ie: exclusive. For example, consider the example “(176, False, 183, False), (183, True, 192, True)”. First pair in each tuple refers to the left endpoint, 2nd refers to the right endpoint. If these were the only intervals in the parameter intervals, you should output an interval with the open left endpoint of 176 and the closed right endpoint of 192. However, if you change the left endpoint of the 2nd interval to False ie:exclusive, you should output the intervals as they are since they are already disjoint intervals.

```
import collections
import functools

from test_framework import generic_test
from test_framework.test_utils import enable_executor_hook

Endpoint = collections.namedtuple('Endpoint', ('is_closed', 'val'))

Interval = collections.namedtuple('Interval', ('left', 'right'))


def union_of_intervals(intervals):
    """
    list of intervals, each interval object has left or right attribute, which is an endpoint object, which hs is_closed
    bool and val attributes
    :param intervals:
    :return:
    """
    # TODO - you fill in here.
    if not intervals: return []
    #sort based on leftmost startpoint
    intervals.sort(key=lambda x:x.left.val)
    res =[]
    for i in range(1,len(intervals)):
        prev = intervals[i-1]
        curr = intervals[i]
        if curr.left.val <prev.right.val:
            #merge
            new = Interval(min([prev.left,curr.left],key=lambda x:(x.val,not x.is_closed)),max([prev.right,curr.right],
                                                                                               key=lambda x:(x.val, x.is_closed)))
            intervals[i] = new
        elif curr.left.val == prev.right.val:
            if not curr.left.is_closed and not prev.right.is_closed:
                res.append(intervals[i - 1])
            else:
                #all True
                new = Interval(min([prev.left, curr.left], key=lambda x: (x.val, not x.is_closed)),
                               max([prev.right, curr.right],
                                   key=lambda x: (x.val, x.is_closed)))
                intervals[i] = new
        else:
            #left of current is greater than right of prev
            res.append(intervals[i - 1])
    res.append(intervals[-1])
    return res
```

I am having a really hard time why my program is not passing all test cases specifically on the EPI testing suite. When I was going through the debugger, my program doesn’t merge the endpoints “(176, False, 183, False), (183, True, 192, True)” , but when I hard coded the actually endpoint objects and tried to merge them using the same logic in my code ie:“don’t merge if and only if the previous right endpoint and the current left endpoint are both False” assuming these points have equal val values, it worked as intended. I found that if i also add a second sort parameter when I first sorted the interval list ie:

```
intervals.sort(key=lambda x:(x.left.val,not x.left.is_closed))
```

my program works as intended and passes all tests. I currently think that this would not matter since i already take care whether an endpoint is a closed or open endpoint in my solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If your current interval is open on the right and the next interval is contiguous, but open on the left, then you are inserting the current interval right away into the result. The problem is that it might happen that later another contiguous interval may come, but that is closed on the left. In this case you would have had to merge them, but you already gave the un-merged interval to be given as part of the result.

Comment: When you sort by left value, if you also put intervals that are closed on the left before intervals with the same left value, but open on the left, then this problem doesn't happen since by the time you receive an interval that is contiguous to your current interval and that is open on the left then you know no closed on the left and contiguous will come later.